# Xamarin iOS FlyoutNavigation menu UIImage has bad quality

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, navigation, uiimage

I have a problem with FlyoutNavigation menu. I have code like this:

```
    _navigation.NavigationRoot = new RootElement("Navigation")
    {
                        new Section(new UIView(){BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0,0,0,0)}, new UIView(){BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0,0,0,0)})
                        {
                            new StyledStringElement ("Home")
                            {
                                BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(255, 233, 203, 255),
                                TextColor = UIColor.Black,
                                Font = UIFont.FromName("Georgia", 16f),
                                Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Icons/ic_home")
                            }

... another StyledStringElemets

        }
```

But my problem is UIImage in my menu has rly bad quality I can see pixels on real device (I tried it on my iPhone SE) prob on simulator iPhone SE is not so bad but on real device it is. I have all menu icons as 25x25 px png.

Is some good solution how UIImage in this navigation make in good quality?

Comment: I see you put the icons in `Icons` folder, do you also add the @2x @3x format file?

Comment: no I have just one icon 25x25 px... You think this can solve my problem? Put  2x 3x format file?

Comment: Yes, 1x image is just used for none-retina screen . But I strongly recommend you to use [Asset Catalog Image](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/displaying-an-image/#asset-catalogs)

Comment: Can u send me some good online generator for this 2x 3x icons? I found some but if u have some good. And which default icon size is best for make these formats?

Comment: Try https://github.com/rickytan/RTImageAssets . And In another way you can use Vector image(just need one pdf file).